# Java - Println is not in order

Tags: java

I have multiple threads printing data. All the data does print; however, they are not in order. Meaning Thread 2 starts printing while Thread 1 is not done yet, which causes inconsistency. How do I guarantee consistency ? Meaning Thread 2 can print once Thread 1 is done.

Comment: do you want both threads to execute concurrently or execute Thread 2 after Thread 1 completes its run?

Comment: execute Thread 2 after Thread 1 completes its run

Comment: so why do you need two threads then?  The whole idea behind threads is to run code concurrently.

Comment: Because both threads work on same data but manipulates differently. I am using semaphore for data synchronization. But when two threads done calculations at almost same time, i get overlapped output. It prints something like 1 2 2 3 1 1 2 1 3. However, I want it in order such as 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3.

Comment: I am printing using standard System.out; I know it is thread safe but it does not let one thread print everything.

Comment: Use a logging framework (instead of `println`).

Comment: @AndrewThompson - that won't make a difference. The order would not be guaranteed any more than `println()` due to thread scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, you are looking to achieve `1 1 1 1 2 2  2 2` so what you'd need to do is actually wait for Thread1 to complete, then start Thread2, like this:

```
Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1();
Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2();

thread1.start();

thread1.join(); // This waits for Thread1 to finish before starting Thread2
thread2.start();
```

however, if you want to have both threads start, but have Thread2 wait part way through its processing, while waiting for Thread1 to complete - this can be done with a few techniques - one in particular comes to mind - using `Semaphore.`

Example:

Ok, firstly define your thread constructors to accept a Semaphore, thus:

```
// Thread2 would be identical wrt the semaphore
public Thread1(Semaphore semaphore) throws InterruptedException
{
  this.semaphore = semaphore; // store semaphore locally
  semaphore.acquire(2);
}
```

Thread1's run method would look like this:

```
public void run()
{
  // .... processing...

  // ... print stuff
  System.out.println("1 1 1 1");
  semaphore.release(); // release 1 permit, allowing thread2 to continue

  // ... more processing

  semaphore.release(); // release last permit.
}
```

Thread2's run method would look something akin to this:

```
public void run()
{
  int permits = 2;
  try
  {
    // .... processing...

    semaphore.acquire(1); // acquire one more permit (will block until Thread1 releases one)
    permits++;

    // ... print stuff
    System.out.println("2 2 2 2");

    // ... more processing      
  }
  catch (InterruptedException ie)
  {
    // interrupted
  }

  semaphore.release(permits); // release permits.
}
```

Now, setting up the threads would be done like this:

```
try
{
  Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(4); // 4 permit semaphore

  Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1(semaphore);
  Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2(semaphore);

  thread1.start();
  thread2.start();

  semaphore.acquire(4);
}
catch (InterruptedException ie)
{
  // interrupt logic...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide example ? Thanks.

Comment: Why bother having threads if you're only going to run them one at a time?

Comment: The semaphore approach would allow both threads to perform processing concurrently, but allow one thread to pause midway, allowing the other thread to continue processing, before resuming itself... am writing an example now...

Comment: Before you do ... think of how you'd need to scale that, and how do you handle an arbitrary number of threads ... ;)

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Obviously we don't know the OP's requirements. So far we only know that they have specified 2 Threads. More threads can require more complex logic. We can only provide answers for what we've been asked.

Comment: Erm ... why? Showing someone, especially a beginner, the proper way to approach a problem is *far* more valuable than a hack that suits their current need.

Comment: Since we do not know the OPs requirements (whether they be professional, or just personal to learn about multithreading), we can only address what we've been given. If the OP wanted a professional enterprise-grade method of doing this, then yes, we'd suggest different mechanisms. However, if the OP is simply learning about multithreading, then introducing a concept such as Semaphore is perfectly acceptable, especially as this is the kind of thing that Semaphores were created for (restricting access to some resources from multiple threads).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code executed by Thread 1 to finish before running Thread 2, then you don't want threads.  You might want to take a look at Java's `ExecutorService`.  Specifically, `Executors. newSingleThreadExecutor()`.  This will allow you to schedule tasks to be run in another thread, but insure that they are run sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's what you want to do (pseudo-code):

```
String results[2];

Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1() {
   public void run() {
      // do stuff; collect output
      results[0] = output
   }
};

Thread2 thread1 = new Thread1() {
   public void run() {
      // do stuff; collect output
      results[1] = output
   }
};

thread1.start();
thread2.start();

thread1.join();
thread2.join();

print result[0];
print result[1];
```

There are better ways of doing above using classes from java.util.concurrent, but this should give you an idea

Comment: only outputting of data is serialized, not the main processing.  So you may still be winning (depending, naturally, on what is going on inside of the run method).

Answer (score 0):

this is how threads work.. if you start two thread it will go something like this 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2

Comment: Yes that is true. I want achieve 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

Comment: No, it won't. There are no guarantees on the order.

Answer (score 0):

Once the run method is done in thread one have it call something in thread two to let it know that it can print

Answer (score 0):

We cannot calculate when a thread is going to run and complete the execution. It completely depends on the CPU. What you can do is have a flag variable at the end of first thread being updated to a value and check for that value before second thread executes.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to save Thread 2 output and print it until Thread 1 is one. Executing them in order as suggested would work too but then, why have Thread's?

Answer (score -1):

You can not randomly print from multiple threads and expect *any* order.

If you need output in an ordered fashion then you're going to have to either synchronize the threads (thus defeating the purpose of having multiple threads) or have the threads pass back the information to output back to the main thread so it can handle ordering and outputting it.

**Edit:** Because I'm bored.

If you're trying to parallelize some work via threads then output the results, you need to have the threads communicate the product of their work back to the main thread and have it do the output. One approach to this is to use queues (this is simple example that relies on the thread order - you may need to get all the results and correlate/sort/etc):

```
public class Worker implements Runnable
{

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> outputQueue;

    public Worker(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> outputQueue)
    {
        this.outputQueue = outputQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

       // Do whatever it is you're doing
       ...
       // place result on queue
       outputQueue.add(result);

    }

} 

public class Main
{

    static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>> myQueues =
            new ArrayList<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>>();

        Thread[] myThreads = new Thread[numThreads];

        // Create queue, create thread with Worker(queue),  
        // start thread
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue =
                new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();

            myQueues.add(queue);           

            myThreads[i] = new Thread(new Worker(queue)).start();

        }

        // Wait for all threads to finish, print their results
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            join(myThreads[i]);

            // Get the queue for the thread we just joined, 
            // pull off each result and output
            Integer j;
            while ((j = myQueues.get(i).poll()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(j);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is off the top of my head, but that's the general approach